# How to find the line offset containing a specific number

Tags: livecode

I am trying to use the following code

```
put 7 into lFoodID

lineoffset (lFoodID,gArrFood) into tArrFoodLine
```

to find the line that contain the number 7 in the array below

```
17  Banana
20  Beans
2   Beef
1   Bread
8   Cabagge
6   Chicken
5   Eggs
15  Ice Cream
3   Mango
7   Pork
18  Rice
4   Salad
19  fried fish
```

It's returning 1. I know that this is because 17 contains the number 7. I have tried

```
set the wholeMatches to true
```

but that does not work either. I believe that regex (^(7) should work  but I can figure out how to use regex in lineoffset.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what you're really after and I wonder if your data really look like what you have provided here. I assume that your data are as displayed, but this may lead do a solution that's slightly different from what you really want.

If you want to get the product associated with an index, you can use the following script

```
put fld 1 into myList
replace space&space with tab in myList
repeat until (tab&tab is not in myList and space&space is not in myList)
   replace space&space with space in myList
   replace tab&tab with tab in myList
end repeat
split myList by cr and tab
put myList[7] into myProduct
put myProduct
```

MyProduct contains the product name. Note that you won't need the repeat loop if your data is formatted properly. If you really want to have the index, use this:

```
put fld 1 into myList
put 7 into myIndex
if word 1 of myList is not myIndex then
   put number of lines of char 1 to offset(cr & "7" & space ,myList) of myList into myLine
else
   put 1 into myLine
end if
put myLine
```

MyLine contains the complete record in your list.

Comment: Thanks Mark, The list is actually derived from a query using `put revDataFromQuery(tab,return,gDatabaseID,"select * from tblFood order by fldfood") into gArrFood` and it is not displayed. It is used as a lookup for another list that is displayed. So I only needed the last part of your code   `put 7 into lFoodID
   split garrfood by cr and tab
   answer garrfood[lFoodID]` which did exactly what I wanted.

Comment: Just an addon question. How do you find the index if you know the product. Eg how do I find which index is holding the product "pork" in the Array once split.

Comment: You'd better do that before splitting the variable into an array and use the same principle: `put the number of lines of (char 1 to offset(tab & "pork" & cr,myList)) into myLine`. If this isn't what you want, perhaps you'd better ask a new question about it.